# Active Admin nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I have the following models in my program:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :groups, through: :group_members 

class GroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :users, through: :group_members
end
```

And I'm using ActiveAdmin to administer these resources. My `groups.rb` file in the admin folder looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do
.
.
  belongs_to :user, :optional => true
.
.
end
```

The problem is, Group is a resource by itself - an admin can manage groups by going to the `/admin/groups` route - but it also is a resource of users, and I'm able to view the user groups by accessing the `/admin/users/:user_id/groups` route. However, when I try to create a new group to this user by accessing the `/admin/users/:user_id/groups/new` page and filling in the form, I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::GroupsController#show
Couldn't find Group with id=13 [WHERE `group_members`.`user_id` = 2]
```

The user id corresponds to my currently logged in user and it is correct, while the group id = 13 corresponds to the id of the newly created group (it is saved in the database correctly), but the association in `group_members` table is not created. Actually, that's not even exactly what I'm trying to achieve here: the ideal scenario would be to retrieve the list of groups and display it in the new page, so as not to create new `groups` in this page - only `group_members`.

How do I proceed in this case? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered removing the

```
belongs_to
```

declaration in the Group register block? The interface nesting that this aa dsl statement gives you, looks nice and gives you a clickpath, but, in the end it is merely a decoration on the data(model). Using filters and scopes in the user model could do as well. If you really need aa's belongs_to you will have to create custom edit screens, and custom redirects. Good luck.